# Copying mail body to new mail in outlook by coding in c#

Tags: c#, outlook

In Outlook 2013, I want the content of the mail body in a new mail programmatically.
Below is my code:

```
void Inspectors_NewInspector(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
{
     Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
     Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
     Outlook.Explorer oExplorer = oApp.ActiveExplorer();
     Outlook.Selection oSelection = oExplorer.Selection;

     foreach (object item in oSelection)
     {
         Outlook.MailItem mi = (Outlook.MailItem)item;
         mailItem.HTMLBody = mi.HTMLBody;
     }
}
```

Everything works fine, but the image present in the original mail is not displayed. Instead it shows something like `cid:image002.png`.

Not sure what is the reason.

Also I want to give it to the client, so I can't save mail content locally.

Comment: did you copy the attachments? thats where the images are usually kept.

Comment: Not sure how to do that. and also if we copy how we will add it in new mail ?

Answer (score 4):

If you see `cid:image002.png` statements in the HTML markup of the message body you need to attach embedded items to new emails as well.

The basic principle of adding an embedded image is to attach the image to the item and then using the HTMLBody to write HTML to add the attachment cid as a reference in the HTML.

```
Attachment attachment = newMail.Attachments.Add(
 @"E:\Pictures\image001.jpg"
, OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem
, null
, "Some image display name"
);

string imageCid = "image001.jpg@123";

attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(
 "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E"
, imageCid
);

newMail.HTMLBody = String.Format(
 "<body><img src=\"cid:{0}\"></body>"
, imageCid
);
```

Be aware, you will need to save the file on disk and the re-attach it to the new email. The [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869553.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of the Attachment class accepts a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment.

Also I'd recommend avoiding the `foreach` loop in the code with OOM objects. Use the for loop instead. It allows to release underlying COM objects instantly. Use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. You can read more about that in the [Systematically Releasing Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article.

Comment: Appreciate ur response. As i am developing it for a project which will be used by different user, to save attachment locally and using it will be tedious. Any other approach !!!

Comment: The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that.

Comment: Use System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName() to get a temp file name, delete it, create a new folder with that name, save the attachment there, add to another message, delete the file and the folder. If using Redemption I an option, its RDOMail.Attachments.Add allows to pass another attachment as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

As i understand you want to copy the attachments from existing mailitem to new one... Then you can try this

```
foreach( var x in mailItem.Attachments)
{
    mi.Attachments.Add(x);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response...first thing have to interchange mailitem and mi. then during runtime it is giving COMException for Add().

Comment: @Eugene working for me in the case of MailMessage.. didn't try on outlook item though

Comment: The asker is talking about OOM, but not MailMessage.